# Playing video on login page as full screen

Tags: ios, swift

I want to play background video on login screen on swift 3.0. But when I run program, video do not working as full screen. It is workingHow can I fix this ? Here is the storyboard picture.

[image]

```
enter code here
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var Player: AVPlayer!
var PlayerLayer: AVPlayerLayer! 


var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


    let URL:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/pattyapp-34c16.appspot.com/o/dog1.mp4?alt=media&token=98ab3c41-c645-4535-a70b-41511b5df602")!


    Player = AVPlayer.init(url: URL as URL)


    PlayerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: Player)
    PlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspect
    PlayerLayer.frame.size = frame.size


    Player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEnd.none
    Player.isMuted = true

    Player.play()

    view.layer.insertSublayer(PlayerLayer, at: 0)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerItemReachEnd(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: Player.currentItem)
}
func playerItemReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {

    Player.seek(to: kCMTimeZero)

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Play video into background you can use the following list of 3rd party library to resolve your problem.

[VideoSplashKit](https://github.com/svtek/VideoSplashKit)

[HAPlayerView](https://github.com/litoarias/HAPlayerView)

Answer (score 0):

Video You are trying to play has dimensions different from layer size. I'd recommend You to try 
`PlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResize`
or
`PlayerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill`